# How to parse a url and convert the url contents into string for Android?

Tags: java, android

How to parse and convert the contents of url into string?

whether this can be done for Android programming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [UrlQuerySanitizer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/UrlQuerySanitizer.html) class.

**EDIT**

[Here](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-download-fileimage-url-your-device) is an article which will show you how to download images/files from a specific URL to your device.

**Second Edit**

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971155/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-scrape-html-webpage-in-android/3081073#3081073).

You can take a look at this [tutorial](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/05/using-xpath-and-html-cleaner-to-parse-html-xml/) also.

Comment: Whether this would get me the full contents of a page say http://www.google.com??

Comment: @Shan: You mean you want to get the PAGE CONTENT of google.com, rather than getting parameter values from URL ?

Answer (score 0):

[What should I do to connect to Server from eclipse - Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968546/what-should-i-do-to-connect-to-server-from-eclipse-android/4969005#4969005)

Check This URL here i posted a complete code to connect to a url and read the entire content . at present it getting in the Log cat you can store it in Strings or anywhere you want