# Syncing Android and Server

Tags: java, android

I don't know what this is called, but it is something like syncing android application and a Web server. Examples are RSS Feeds and Weather Forecast

Does anyone know the concept behind developing application? I mean how do you sync the Android phone with a web server. Is there any programming needed in the server side and the client side(Android)

Are there any programming books that tackles this subject? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[What should I do to connect to Server from eclipse - Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968546/what-should-i-do-to-connect-to-server-from-eclipse-android/4969005#4969005)

check the whole conversation here

Comment: syncing means nothing more then hitting a url and reading the content and saving it in you application data buffer to be used in your app

Comment: The code he wrote looks fine. just to add this, you'll have to keep polling the web server on regular intervals.

Answer (score 0):

The server should make the data available in a meaningfull parsable format (for machines). For example RSS/XML feeds, etc. Your application should poll frequently and updates the status/screen.

Comment: How about if it is in database. Does the same thing applies?

Comment: I mean sensitive information like inventory or hospital records?